# Call WordPress API and print result to Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress, jwt

I am new to API development.

Currently I am trying to build a small dashboard that can read data such as installed plugins, plugin version and theme name. My question is how to configure JWT in Laravel so I can fill my template with the data there. Or is there another way?

I have already set up a test environment with WordPress and installed a JWT plugin. With Postman I get data output and can query different endpoints.

Comment: https://adevait.com/laravel/using-corcel-in-laravel Here is some documentation to help you get started, when you have some code feel free to post it here!